# OpenGL (ES): Can an implementation optimize fragments resulting from overdraw?

Tags: opengl-es

I wanted to come up with a crude way to "benchmark" the performance improvement of a tweak I made to a fragment shader (to be specific, I wanted to test the performance impact of the removal of the computation of the gamma for the resulting color using `pow` in the fragment shader).

So I figured that if a frame was taking 1ms to render an opaque cube model using my shader that if I set `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` and loop my render call 100 times, that the frame would take 100ms to render.

I was wrong. Rendering it 100 times only results in about a 10x slowdown. Obviously if depth test is still enabled, most if not all of the fragments in the second and subsequent draw calls would not be computed because they would all fail the depth test.

However I must still be experiencing a lot of fragment culls even with depth test off.

My question is about whether my hardware (in this particular situation it is an iPad3 on iOS6.1 that I am experiencing this on -- a PowerVR SGX543MP4) is just being incredibly smart and is actually able to use the geometry of later draw calls to occlude and discard fragments from the earlier geometry. If this is not what's happening, then I cannot explain the better-than-expected performance that I am seeing. The question applies to all flavors of OpenGL and desktop GPUs as well, though.

Edit: I think an easy way to "get around" this optimization might be `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` or something of that sort. I will try this and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerVR hardware is based on [tile-based deferred rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile-based_deferred_rendering). It does not begin drawing fragments until ***after*** it receives all of the geometry information for a tile on screen. This is a more advanced hidden-surface removal technique than z-buffering, and what you have actually discovered here is that enabling alpha blending breaks the hardware's ability to exploit this.

Alpha blending is very order-dependent, and so no longer can rasterization and shading be deferred to the point where only the top-most geometry in a tile has to be drawn. Without alpha blending, since there is no data dependency on the order things are drawn in, completely obscured geometry can  be skipped before expensive per-fragment operations occur. It is only when you start blending fragments that a true order-dependent situation arises and completely destroys the hardware's ability to defer/cull fragment processing for hidden surfaces.

In all honesty, if you are trying to optimize for a platform based on PowerVR hardware you should probably make this one of your goals. By that, I mean, before optimizing shaders first consider whether you are drawing things in an order and/or with states that hurt the PowerVR hardware's ability to do TBDR. As you have just discovered, blending is considerably more expensive on PowerVR hardware than other hardware... the operation itself is no more complicated, it just prevents PVR hardware from working the special way it was designed to.

Comment: Makes sense. I clearly was making good use of the TBDR's techniques because `GL_BLEND` wasn't even enabled, and I'll disable it again now that I'm done with my testing. It is also one of the points addressed by almost every guide specific to iOS OpenGL development, pointing out that alpha blending is *especially* expensive.

Comment: Myth debunking: blending is not expensive on PowerVR HW - in fact it's cheaper than on other architectures since it can be done on-chip without reading/writing to a buffer in main memory. That said, allowing PowerVR's TBDR to avoid drawing fragments at all is even cheaper and the difference is noticeable when blending stops that from happening.

Comment: @gmaclachlan: That is what I meant by *" ... the operation itself is no more complicated"*. When you fail to exploit TBDR, alpha blending is more expensive in contrast to drawing opaque geometry. The difference between best- (opaque) and worst-case (alpha blended) performance is a lot more noticeable on PVR hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that only after adding both lines:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

did the frame render time increase in a linear fashion in response to the repeated draw calls. Now back to my crude benchmarking.